# Amazon S3 server logging : configure how often log files are generated

Tags: logging, amazon-s3

I have a bucket on S3 for which I wish to get some special information (how many times the files were downloaded, by how many unique people, etc.). S3 does not provide such information through the API, so I enabled [Server Access Logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html).

However, each log file seems to only have one single entry, which means I get a lot of files for not too much info. From the docs :

> Amazon S3 **periodically** collects access log records, consolidates the records in log files, and then uploads log files to your target bucket as log objects.

Not sure what periodically means for them, but I would love to have a way to only get one log file/day, for example. I have yet to find a way to configure it this way.

Anyone encountered the same problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See ["Best Effort Server Log Delivery"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html#LogDeliveryBestEffort).

Quoting: Server access log records are delivered on a best effort basis. Most requests for a bucket that is properly configured for logging will result in a delivered log record, and most log records will be delivered within a few hours of the time that they were recorded.

Answer (score 1):

Its random, as in not regular intervals. I have seen 5 per hour and sometimes single lines per file on low traffic buckets and 5 per minute from high traffic buckets with many lines per file. You have to aggregate your logs by yourself anyway. You seem to have small log files so maybe you could use a script like [this](https://github.com/mozilla/version-control-tools/blob/40335c530d33a726d8179e70a7fc0e1cb1d2436b/scripts/aggregate-s3-bucket-logs). If you get lots of traffic you may want to use a log analysis service.